# Search only in non-folded, visible code

Tags: text-editors, find-and-replace, sublime-text-2, code-folding

Is there any way to set Sublime Text 2's search feature to only search in code that is not folded? i.e. limit the scope of Find or Find/Change to only visible code, excluding folded code?

For example, suppose I have everything folded so only function names show. Can I search only in these i.e. searching only in these function names? Or maybe I've folded everything except 9 function which are related to some process: can I search only in these unfolded functions?

The default behaviour is to search everything, and to unfold any folds if a match is found within them. I'd like to set it to skip folded code, and never unfold anything.

None of the available options look relevant, and I can't find anything online.

---

*(Curiously, when `In section` is ticked, I get very strange find behaviour if any code is folded: it struggles to find anything at all, folded or unfolded, even when everything is selected. I'm not sure if this is related or not: I suspect it's a bug unrelated to my question, but it might be a sign I've misunderstood something about how Find works when some code is folded. My expectation was that Find In Selection wouldn't change its behaviour when some code is folded)*

Comment: From what the options list while in there and browsing the packages on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) There isn't a way.

Comment: @MrStatic any updates on this?